# What might cause noisy gesture demonstration video clips?

Tags: macos, video

I'm getting multicolor noisy gesture demonstration video clips after each reboot. However, they gradually improve after a while and eventually become fully watchable (about 15-20seconds). Does anyone know what's causing this and how to fix it? I'm on Mavericks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you mean instruction video clips@?

Comment: The pane on the right that demonstrates what each gesture means physically.

Comment: Ahh Ok i'm with you. Does this happen when you play clips in quicktime?

Comment: Well, no. However, I'm getting similar multicoloured noisy file icons and covers in Cover Flow for many files in Finder. I can preview the videos in Cover Flow though. It's just the icons there in Finder.

Comment: Well I don't have this issue in Mavericks, so it sounds like it could be either, A) A hardware problem with your graphics card or B) A corrupt install. Are you in a position to do a clean reinstall?

Comment: I'd prefer not to. :( It's just very strange that the gesture clips gradually improve and eventually become fully watchable.

Comment: @Kate which Mac are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has something to do with loading time. In Cover Flow, for some files, if I wait for a few seconds, the icons within range in Cover Flow load up. However, the file icons themselves remain as multicoloured noise.

Comment: @JohnWoods It's a 2009 21.5" iMac.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11723/discussion-between-john-woods-and-kate)

Comment: can you check you console for this message : NVDA(OpenGL): Channel exception!

Comment: @JohnWoods Right. Whereabouts in the console should I look?